# LLDB setting arguments from external program or shell

Tags: shell, gdb, lldb

I'm starting to use LLDB as an alternative for GDB. Normally I can invoke debugger for specific target with

```
$ gdb target
(gdb) set args `python -c 'print "a"*200'`
```

or alternatively,

```
$ gdb target
(gdb) set args $(python -c 'print "a"*200')
```

which means I can invoke Python in shell and use its piped output as arguments in GDB. But I cannot do it in LLDB even LLDB is similar to GDB in many ways.

```
$ lldb target
(lldb) settings set target.run-args `python -c 'print "a"*200'`
```

I know it could be done by

```
$ lldb target -- `python -c 'print "a"*200'`
```

at the very beginning, however, later I cannot change arguments without quitting LLDB. Any better idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The backtick version is running a foul of lldb's use of backticks to mean "evaluate the string in backticks as an expression in the current contents and replace the contents into the command argument.  Backslashing the backtick should work but it looks like the command parser drops the backticks in that case.  Please file a bug about this to the bug reporter at lldb.llvm.org...

The "$(" version will work with one proviso, the command parser starts out by looking for options in the input of the command, so it takes the `-c` to be an option for `settings set`.  But you can work around that by backslash protecting the "-" like:

```
(lldb) set set target.run-args  $(python \-c 'print "a"*200')
(lldb) run
Process 12940 launched: '/bin/ls' (x86_64)
ls: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa: No such file or directory
Process 12940 exited with status = 1 (0x00000001)
```

Comment: I tested backslash added before `-c`, and `\-c` is still parsed as a second argument. It returns `lldb: unrecognized option \`-c'` and
`error: unknown or ambiguous option`. So I added backslash before space to make sure there is no ambiguity, and this time it is parsed as a shell command. But when I run the program, it show `/bin/sh: python -c print "a"*200: command not found`, I guess the command (python) is not invoked in shell. I tested LLDB 3.5 on both OS X 10.10 and Fedora 21. Can you give a little more instruction? Many thanks.

Comment: Putting a backslash before the space is going to tie python & \c together, so it makes sense that didn't work.

Comment: I tried the line I showed above in TOT SVN lldb & lldb from Xcode6.3 and both worked.  Can you show me what happened when you tried that line?

Answer (score 0):

just run 'run arg1 arg2' in lldb , solved this problem for me!