# LLDB pass bash command output as arg to application

Tags: linux, llvm, lldb

I am trying to debug a program using lldb and I want to start the program with different arguments. Is it possible to pass the output of a bash command to a program when you start it in lldb?

As an example from bash I can do the following:

```
lldb program $(cat file.txt)
```

And the program will start with the contents of file.txt passed as the first argument.

When I am inside lldb I can run `platform shell cat file.txt` to get the contents of file and I can use either `run -- args` or `process launch -- args` to launch a process with a set of arguments.

However when trying to do this using `run` or `process launch` combined with `platform shell command` I get the command passed as the argument.

So as an example if I ran the command `run -- platform shell cat file.txt` and then `settings show target.run-args` I would get the following output:

```
[0]: "--"
  [1]: "platform"
  [2]: "shell"
  [3]: "cat"
  [4]: "file.txt"
```

I have tried all of the following with no success:

```
run -- platform shell cat payload.txt
run platform shell cat payload.txt
process launch -- platform shell cat payload.txt
process launch platform shell cat payload.txt
process launch -- platform shell $(cat payload.txt)
A whole bunch more combinations like this.
```

I have also searched for similar questions and found a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33424637/what-is-the-lldb-equivalent-of-gdbs-args) [however](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785781/lldb-setting-arguments-from-external-program-or-shell) [none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974797/how-can-arguments-be-passed-to-executable-given-for-lldb-in-a-vscode-launch-json) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436300/how-to-pass-arguments-to-mac-terminal-in-llldb-mode) [them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595449/passing-characters-and-non-printable-values-into-lldb-as-arguments) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70767028/lldb-using-python-output-to-generate-arguments) getting me the results I want.

I feel like I am close to getting this right but not quite getting the syntax correct. Does anyone have any examples of how to do this correctly?

Comment: Have you tried `lldb -- program $(cat file.txt)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to get shell expansion is:

(lldb) process launch -X 1 -- arg1 arg2

But it looks like when handling an arg of the form `$(aaa bbb)` lldb inserts one too many levels of backslash in trying to form the arguments to pass to the process so this construct doesn't get substituted.  It works for simple things like "$HOME" but not the "$(...)" construct.

Comment: Remember as well that lldb is a "space separated" command line, and we pass the lldb arguments to `process launch` one-to-one to the process we launch.  So be sure to put quotes around any arguments that contain spaces in the `process launch` command line.